# How to delete queue updates in telegram api?

Tags: python, api, telegram

I'm trying to delete messages from /getUpdates in telegram API but I didn't know how..
I tried to use /deleteMessage

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/deleteMessage?chat_id=blahblah&message_id=BlahBlah
```

But it didn't delete message from API database..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Call [`getUpdates()`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) with the `offset` parameter set to the last message's id, incremented by `1`

---

We'll need to let Telegram know which message's we've processed. To do this, set the `offset` parameter to the `update_id + 1` of the last message your script has processed.

1. Call `getUpdates()` to get the `update_id` of the latest message

   ```
   https://api.telegram.org/<MY-TOKEN>/getUpdates
   ```

   ```json
   {
       "ok": true,
           "result": [
               {
                   "update_id": 343126593,   # <-- Remember / Save this id
                   "message": {
                   ...
   ```
2. Increment the `update_id` by `1`
3. On the next `getUpdates()` call, set the `offset` parameter to the id:

   ```
   https://api.telegram.org/<MY-TOKEN>/getUpdates?offset=343126594
   ```

---

[image]

Comment: Yep !, thanks but actually in the next time it should be offset + 1

Answer (score 4):

To **delete all messages** find update id of last message of the queue..

[image]

here  *"836737487"*, so run on browser

```
"https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getupdates?offset=836737488"
```

[note: offset integer value will be higher than update_id of last message]

and if you want to **delete specific message** then set offset value as update_id of the next message of that specific message

Comment: This helped me, while offsetting messageId didn't, thanks!