# How to delete all queue updates in telegram api?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to delete all messages (updates) but for some reason there is always a message in the list. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

**GET UPDATES**

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_ID}/getUpdates
```

**DELETE MESSAGE (UPDATE)**

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_ID}/getUpdates?offset={UPDATE_ID}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete queue updates in telegram api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976560/how-to-delete-queue-updates-in-telegram-api)

Comment: What does the second url returns? Try `UPDATE_ID + 1`

Comment: 0stone0, solved! UPDATE_ID +1 :D