# Is there a way to record ALL conversations my telegram bot has with any user?

Tags: telegram-bot

I've created a telegram bot on python to collect information from users. Essentially I want users to forward to the bot a message they received within telegram, and answer some follow up questions on them in which they will answer by clicking the built in commands I've set. I want to find a way to extract all of these conversations users have with my bot as the bot owner.

Is there any other simple way besides using - [https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btoken%7D/getUpdates) ?

I've tried using Webhooks but it seems too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find a way to extract all of these conversations users have with my bot as the bot owner.

No, Telegram does not 'remember' any user input, expect what you can find in the `getUpdates` call. Remember that you should [empty that message queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61976560/how-to-delete-queue-updates-in-telegram-api).

If you want to 'save' that information, you'll need to save it by yourself, eg in a database.